# mv command to move and rename set of files

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, rename

I am using mv command to move a set of files from one folder to another that involves renaming the files also.

```
   mv <SRC_PATH>/ABC_$t1.dat <DEST_PATH>/ABC_$t1_$$.dat
```

I am using the above code for a set of files. Only difference is in the name of files are value of variable $t1.
For example:

```
  while loop required times
  do    
    t1=<GetValueOfT1 >
    mv <SRC_PATH>/ABC_$t1.dat <DEST_PATH>/ABC_$t1_$$.dat
  done
```

In the above code t1 will have value of 123,234,345.

So if I have ABC_123.dat, ABC_234.dat, ABC_345.dat in source directory then my destination directory will have ABC_123_1808.dat, ABC_234_1808.dat, ABC_345_1808.dat given 1808 is the pid.

But after all the move destination path only holds the last file.
If I removed the "$$" from the destination name then there is no problem.
For example:

```
  mv <SRC_PATH>/ABC_$t1.dat <DEST_PATH>/ABC_$t1.dat
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: how do u assigning the value to `$t1` ?

Comment: @WissamAl-Roujoulah hope the edit helps

Comment: `ABC_$t1_$$.dat` should be `ABC_${t1}_$$.dat` or else the shell will interpret `$t1_` as a variable name. Also **quote your variables**.

Comment: @fuzzy i finished my edit you can check it

Answer (score 2):

[Commands exist](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x4055.htm) for that kind of mass renaming.

Personally, I use `mmv`:

```
mmv <SRC_PATH>/"ABC_*.dat" <DEST_PATH>/"ABC_#1_$$.dat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a variable `t1` that contains a comma separated set of values:

```
t1=$(GetValueOfT1)    # For example t1='123,456,789'
```

You can apply each of these in turn with a loop like this

```
OIFS="$IFS" IFS=,
for v in $t1
do
    echo "Processing with v=$v:" >&2
    mv "$SRC_PATH/ABC_${v}.dat" "$DEST_PATH/ABC_${v}_$$.dat"
done
IFS="$OIFS"
```

The first `$t1` must not be quoted because we need the shell to split the value at its comma characters. (This is controlled by the shell variable `$IFS`, which we save so that we can restored it at the end of the loop.) The remaining variables should all be quoted to protect them against unexpected word splitting on whitespace, commas, etc. Finally, you have to present `$v` as `${v}` because otherwise the shell will include the immediately following `_` character as part of the variable name, and `$v_` isn't what we want.

I'd recommend you prefix the `mv` with `echo` (i.e. `echo mv ...`) before running this for real, so you can examine the output before it changes anything.